# Upgrade to Azure 1.7 now connecting to different dev storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I have just upgraded to the Azure 1.7 sdk and have now lost the contents of my devstorage.

I can still see it in the local instance of sqlexpress (as DevelopmentStorage20110606), but when I use UseDevelopmentStorage=true, it longer connects to this.

Where has the new development storage db gone? I need to import my data from the previous version, as we use local storage for testing on the build server and have test data setup on it, or is there an upgrade script to be able to port this data accross.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

SDK 1.7 now uses IIS Express (compute) and SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB (storage). You should be able to point your emulator to your existing database by running dsinit.

Michael Collier talks about the 1.6 vs. 1.7 differences in his post, [here](http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/whats-new-for-the-windows-azure-developer-lots-2/).

More information about LocalDB is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx).

DSInit documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433005.aspx).

Comment: Thanks David, manage to use DSInit to connect to old storage db, exported data, repointed to new db, and away you go.

Comment: Sorry David, just taking this off as not solved. Can you run DSIninit and make it point to the old database ie developmentstoragedb20110816 instead of development storagedb201206.

If I use dsiniti/sqlinstance:sqlexpress /server:MyMachineName all it does is create a new db in the sqlexpress instance called developmentstoregedb201206. 

The schema seemed to have changed slightly, especially in the BlockData column where the Data (varbinary) field has been removed and replaced with a StartOffset (BigInt) field.

Is there a way to upgarde the data within the old database schema into the new one?